# How to make the inline output latex ready in Rmd files?

Tags: r, knitr

I use Rstudio to create my .Rmd documents, in order to combine the markdown ease-of-use with some neat equation support. 
I mainly use the inline code syntax `r bla` for evaluation of arguments in an equation (between $...$) in my .Rmd documents. The problem is that if a result is transformed in the scientific notation, it just screws up the entire equation, which is not displayed correctly:

````
```{r}
bla = 123456789
bli = 2
```

$$
B = `r bli`
$$

$$
B = `r bla`
$$
````

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine the `inline` hook so that numbers can be formatted using LaTeX notation:

```
knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) {
  if (is.numeric(x)) knitr:::format_sci(x, 'latex') else x
})
```

(Put this inside your Rmd document)